# Create a graph of a pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I create a pivot table and I want create a bar graph. This is my pivot_table:

[image: Information]

I don't know how to extract the values of the column 1970 and use this information to make a bar graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert dataframe column names to `str` then you can select the data of  year `1970` with `df['1970']`. Then, you can use `pandas` built-in `plot.bar` method to make a bar plot. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#converting column names to string
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

#plotting a bar plot
df['1970'].plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

**Examples based on @AlanDyke DataFrame**:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1970,'a',1],
                   [1970,'b',2],
                   [1971,'a',2],
                   [1971,'b',3]],
                   columns=['year','location', 'value'])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index='location', columns='year')
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
df['1970'].plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please consider accepting/check-marking the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use plt.bar and slice the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1970,'a',1],
                   [1970,'b',2], 
                   [1971,'a',2],
                   [1971,'b',3]],
                   columns=['year','location', 'value'])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index='location', columns='year')
plt.bar(list(df.transpose().columns), height=df[1970])
```